# Cisco: How Do I Remove a LAN Network From a Router?

Tags: cisco, router, lan

I know this is probably a simple question, but for some reason I cannot think of a command. I am using RIPv2 configuration, and simply need to remove a LAN address from the router. Can anyone give me a quick walk through?

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want to remove the address from a router interface? You need to explain, and provide more information. Edit your question to include the router configuration.

Comment: Yes, that is all I need to know. How do I remove it from a router interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove an address from a router interface, you use either use the `no` form of the command in the interface configuration:

```
interface <slot/port>
 no ip address <address> <mask>
```

or you can simply assign a different address, overwriting the existing address and mask.